# How can I use SimpleFormController with Validator with Spring 3?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring 3 and using SimpleFormController is deprecated. It sounds like we should use annotions like @Controller instead.
Okay, but how can I manage the validator for my form within my controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still some issues with 3.0RC1, see the following issue if you want to look at annotation based validation and JSR 303: http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-6189

Answer (score 1):

Spring 3 has shiny new support for JSR 303 validation. See the docs [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/ch05s07.html#validation.mvc).